# Bootstrap 3.0 input controls placeholder text bold

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to figure out how to bold the placeholder text for my input controls in bootstrap.

For example

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Since placeholder is html5 form input element attribute.
So if you want to style the placeholder attribute you need to use following CSS

```
:-moz-placeholder {
    font-weight: bold;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-weight: bold;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
    font-weight: bold;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```